# How to change the value depending on one input when another input is checked? React hooks

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

In my component I have input range which have 5 values and for each there is price assign. I also have input checkbox with which I want to apply extra discount. So when it is set to true I want to use discount. Should I write another function or maybe I can use one of the functions I have already written?

```
const Cost = () => {

    const arr = data.map(arr => arr)//here I have array with data like   {"range": 3,"views": 100,"price":16
    },

    const [value, setValue] = useState(arr[2])//default value for range
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)//default value for checkbox

    function handleChangeValue(e) {
        setValue(arr[e.target.value - 1])
    }//changing price when range is changed


    function toggleChange() {
        setChecked(prev => !prev)
    }//changing checkbox

    return (
        <>
            <Views>{value.views} pageviews</Views>
            <Input
                value={value.range}
                onChange={handleChangeValue}
                type="range"
                name="range"
                min="1"
                max="5"
                list="views">
            </Input>
            <Price><span>${value.price}</span>/month</Price>//this is price which I want to  change
            <Switch onClick={toggleChange} >
                <label className="switch" htmlFor="toggle">
                    <input name="toggle" type="checkbox" aria-label="toggle" checked={checked} />//when this is set to true I want to apply extra 25% discount to my price
                    <span className="slider"></span>
                </label>
            </Switch>


        </>
    )
}
```

At first I wanted to create two different components for those inputs but wasn't sure how I could have change the price then.

To sum up - price is changed when range is changed and when checkbox is true. Can you guys advise?

UPDATE

```
    const [newPrice, setNewPrice] = useState(arr[2].price);
   useEffect(() => {
        let newPrice = value.price
        if (checked) {
            newPrice -= 0.25 * newPrice;

        } else {
            return newPrice
        }

        setNewPrice(newPrice)

    }, [value, checked])
```

It does apply discount when I set checkbox to true but when I am switching it back to false, price is still with discount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe don't get all of the matter. But I think you should take a look at the [useEffect() hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

It triggers a function each time some dependancies values changed
( here `checked, range or value` )

```
// considering you have some useState keeping the cost somewhere :
const [cost, setCost] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    let newCost = value[range];
    if(checked){
       // apply extra disount
       newCost -= newCost * 25/100;
    }
   setCost(newCost)
}, [checked, range, value])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do have one issue - Code does apply discount when I set checkbox to true but when I am switching it back to false, price is still with discount. I have updated my question.

Comment: I took a look at your update ... And the problem is linked to the "return" statement in the useEffect... Why return ? It seems that you don't fully get what it does .... Hint : When you "return" the end of the function isn't executed ... ;)

Comment: I have removed whole "else" part and now it is working perfectly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

```
    const [newPrice, setNewPrice] = useState(arr[2].price);

    useEffect(() => {
        let newPrice = value.price
        if (checked) {
            newPrice -= 0.25 * newPrice;

        }

        setNewPrice(newPrice)

    }, [value, checked])
```